# Importing tracking.js into an angular project

Tags: javascript, angular

1. I have downloaded [tracking.js](https://trackingjs.com/docs.html) and added it to my /src/assets folder
2. In my angular-cli.json file I have added to my scripts:

> "scripts": [
>           "../src/assets/tracking/build/tracking-min.js"
>         ],

3. *issue here* - In my angular component, I import tracking as follows:

> import tracking from 'tracking';

and in the chrome inspection window I can hover over 'tracking' and see all of the properties as shown:

[image]

I can even call the ColorImage constructor in the console window! :

[image]

However when it tries to execute the constructor in my code I get the error about tracking being undefined:
[image]

I had assumed it was because I wasn't passing in the tracking object through the constructor in the traditional DI fashion, but when doing so I got the error that the namespace couldn't be used as a type:
[image]

The only other thing I could think of was to try and add the external reference in the main index.html file, but I got an error about strict MIME checking.

To clarify: this is all happening in my angular component constructor (when the tracking methods get exercised)

Any ideas?

Comment: its because tracking has no exported module . find more info here :

https://github.com/eduardolundgren/tracking.js/issues/177

Comment: I don't know too much about CommonJS vs ES6, but based off your link I also found this specific tracking.js issue that talks about exported modules: https://github.com/eduardolundgren/tracking.js/issues/206

I guess my question is now what do I do with either the line '
module.exports = window.tracking' or 'export default window.tracking'? 

Do I have to add this to the bottom of my 'tracking.js' file as well as the minified version? The tracking.js file has a ton of functions (`(function(window, undefined) {..}) '), do they all require a export at the end of each of them?

Comment: no , just export the window.tracking . u can access all other functions with this "window.tracking" object .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your node_modules folder and find this file : "node_modules/tracking/build/tracking.js" . open the file and add this line of code to end of the file :

```
module.exports = window.tracking
```

save file and in use this code to import it :

```
import * as tracking from 'tracking';
```

Comment: When I add 'module.exports = window.tracking' to that file, in Chrome I end up seeing an exception in my resulting 'scripts.bundle.js' file on that line, with the error: 'ReferenceError: module is not defined'

Comment: the 'window.tracking' variable in the 'scripts.bundle.js' is populated and looks fine, its just the module variable itself is undefined. Searching away... thanks for the help so far. Maybe its something to do with how I am loading these modules and referencing this tracking.js file though my angular-cli.json file.

Comment: do u use webpack to build the bundles ?

Comment: I see a reference to "webpack-bundle-analyzer", so I want to say yes

Comment: one more question . do u use angular-cli?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176969/discussion-between-asdf-and-soroush-neshat).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use DI with that external library. However, you should be able to create a new instance in the constructor:

```
import tracking from 'tracking';

constructor(...) {
    this.colors = new tracking.ColorTracker(...);
}

myFunction() {
    this.colors.doWhateverIWant();   
}
```

If you only want a single tracking instance throughout your app, then you'll have to create your own `trackingService` and inject that.

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to reference the tracking.js via script tag :

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tracking.js/1.1.3/tracking- 
        min.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

and in your component.ts write :

```
(window as any).tracking.ColorTracker(["magenta"]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I try to load scripts ion directly like that I get the error: "Refused to execute script from '' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."